# Cakephp and Postgres, table relations

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, orm, relationship

The question is simple (and maybe silly):

When I create the tables in Postgres, do I have to also create the relations? I ask this because I have used an orm before and had issues with some relations, specially multiple primary keys, so I had to re-do all the db structure with the orm.

I was thinking about having only tables without relations and using cake's $hasMany, $belongsTo variables to manage the relations. will this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "relations" ... do you mean "foreign key relationships" ? "Relations" in SQL means something specific and totally different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CakePHP's `$hasMany` and `$belongsTo` are accessing the database's relationships.
So you have to create them.